# How can I test this correctly with jest?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vitest

I am a little lost here.
I am using vue and attempting to test a particular method that I just can't seem to get to work.

I have this method that I am trying to test

```
const onRestrictionField = async (
  error: Error,
  config: FileConfig
): Promise<void> => {
  const { heading, text } = getAlert(error, config);

  await swal.alert(heading, { text });
};
```

seems simple enough.  `getAlert` is just a method that returns specific text based on the error.

swal is imported as `const swal = useSwal()`

useSwal is a wrapper around sweet alert

```
class SweetAlert {
  defaultOptions = {
    closeOnClickOutside: false,
    closeOnEsc: false,
    dangerMode: false,
    buttons: {
      confirm: { text: t('app.ok'), visible: true },
    },
  };

  // fire the alert type modal
  async alert(
    message: string,
    config?: SweetAlertOptions
  ): Promise<SweetAlertValue> {
    const icon = SweetAlertIcons.INFO as string;
    const options = {
      ...this.defaultOptions,
      icon,
      title: message,
      ...config,
    };

    return swal({ ...options });
  }
}
export const useSwal = () => new SweetAlert();
```

In my spec file I have tried

```
import { onRestrictionField } from './files';
import { useSwal } from '@/helpers';

jest.mock('@/helpers', () => {
  return {
    useSwal: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log('a nice swal');
      return {
        alert: jest.fn(),
      };
    }),
  };
});

...

it ('will call swal with the correct arguments', () => {
      const error = new Error('You can only upload: .jpg, .png files');
      const config = {
        fileTypesMessage: 'yip',
        fileTypes: ['.jpg', '.png'],
        maxFileSize: 100,
        limit: 5,
      };

      onRestrictionField(error, config);

      const { alert } = useSwal();
      expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('File type not allowed', {
        text: 'Sorry the file type is not allowed, please upload a file with one of the following extensions: .jpg, .png',
      });
})
```

if I console out alert within the test it has the usual mock stuff I would expect.
if I console out alert within the actual file, then its the actual class, and I get the following error
`AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ 'File type not allowed', …(1) ]`

I do also get the `a nice swal` consoled when running the test.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Don't you get `a nice swal` twice? When you call `useSwal()` in your tests, you get a different `jest.fn()` that doesn't get called.

Comment: it just fired the once